# What is the best way to orally administer a water insoluble powdered drug to macaque monkeys?

Tags: pharmacology, medicine

They typically need to be given ~150mg, once a day, and it'll last for two weeks. The drug is very water insoluble, becomes almost like a paste, not suitable for tube feeding. And yes, this is for for real lifesaving medical research.

The best we can come up with right now is putting them to sleep, mixing the powder into Nutella, and putting it under their tongue. The idea being they'll wake up and swallow the mixture.

Comment: I'd give this a veterinary tag, but it doesn't exist, and I don't have enough points.

Comment: So what's it soluble with? Could you dissolve it in oils, like coconut oil? I suppose it tastes too bad to just mix it with mashed bananas?

Comment: Can you mix it with food? Especially something what your macaques like?

Comment: Could you not suspend it in some liquid?

Answer (score 2):

If it is not water-soluble (lipophobic or hydrophilic), the only other alternative would be that it is fat-soluble (lipophilic or hydrophobic). Consider adding the powder to fatty solids or liquids which can be absorbed from the GI tract into the vascular system, if that is where you'd like the drug to go to be distributed throughout the body. Ideally, you would need to look up the target concentration of the drug within the blood in order to be effective, its volume of distribution, its bioavailability, its half-life, mechanism of metabolism, and calculate from there how much you would really need in order to last the full 2 weeks.

Comment: Thing's aren't always water or oil soluble, I've tried to dissolve indigo dye in several organic solvents with no luck. Of course any drug as insoluble as indigo would have terrible pharmacological properties.